# Does "data" in Cauchy data come before or after the coinage of data in computer science

Tags: terminology, math-history

Is the usage of data as in Cauchy data (i.e. initial conditions) borrowed or came before the usage of data in computer science and do both usages mean roughly the same thing (data ~ information)?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? The word is 350 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of "data" in mathematics is quite old.  Oxford English Dictionary has a quote from 
1645:   T. Urquhart Trissotetras 53

> The verticall Angles, according to the diversity of the three Cases
>   being by the foresaid Datas thus obtained.

I would suspect that its use in Latin is much older (as well as the use of the equivalent Greek term).  What does Euclid use for what is "given" in a geometric construction?

Comment: Okay because I came across this term in a computational PDE text so I thought what's traditionally simply referred to as "initial condition" might have gotten a computational spin, hence the term "cauchy data" it would be interesting to know when this term, the entire term "cauchy data" was coined and I doubt it was coined during cauchy's time

Comment: I found "Cauchy data" e.g. in Math Reviews from 1941 (MR0003909), with no indication that this was anything other than standard terminology.  This was long before there was such a thing as Computer Science.